# Querying Magento API in Go

Tags: json, magento, go, oauth

I am building a service in Go that queries a Magento API.

I already have the oauth credentials needed to make the request (these are persistent) and am able to successfully query the API in Postman.

I am trying to query the Magento API using this package, however every time I make the request I get an error:

> Service temporary unavailable

I have searched around and it looks like this is a common error to get when the request does not have a header for `Accept: application/json`.

I am using [this package](https://github.com/dghubble/oauth1) to sign my requests currently and cannot see any way to add this header. I am open to using a different package if required, it just needs to support oauth1 authentication.

Being relatively new to Go, I'm not too sure how to add the header to my request and would love some help.

This is my current code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "github.com/dghubble/oauth1"
)

func main() {

    config := oauth1.NewConfig("consumer key", "consumer secret")
    token := oauth1.NewToken("token key", "token secret")

    httpClient := config.Client(oauth1.NoContext, token)

    path := "https://www.example.com/api/rest/customers?limit=2&order=created_at&dir=DESC"
    resp, err := httpClient.Get(path)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Printf("Raw Resonse Body:\n%v\n", string(body))
}
```

**How can I add the** `Accept: application/json` **header to my request?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a request:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", path, nil)
if err != nil {
     // handle error
}
```

Set the headers:

```
req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")
```

Run the request using client as configured in the question:

```
resp, err := httpClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
     // handle error
}
```

Example that worked for me:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/dghubble/oauth1"
)

func main() {

    config := oauth1.NewConfig("consumer key", "consumer secret")
    token := oauth1.NewToken("token key", "token secret")

    httpClient := config.Client(oauth1.NoContext, token)

    path := "https://www.example.com/api/rest/customers?limit=2&order=created_at&dir=DESC"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", path, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")

    resp, err := httpClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Printf("Raw Resonse Body:\n%v\n", string(body))
}
```

Output:

```
Raw Resonse Body:
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
      <title>Example Domain</title>
      ...
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
      ...
```

Comment: How do I do the above whilst implementing oauth1 authentication with the request though? I tried to add the `.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")` already and it was invalid (due to the package I am using??)

Comment: Swapped the package and got it working with the `.Header.Set()`. Thanks for your input.

Comment: weird it seems that oauth1 package uses the native http.Client from go also https://github.com/dghubble/oauth1/blob/master/config.go#L42

Comment: Interesting... how would you have added it in to my code sample? I'm happy to try it out.

Comment: This did indeed work - given this more closely answers my original question - I will mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I finally have this working after countless hours spent on it - I swapped the oauth package from [dghubble/oauth1](https://github.com/dghubble/oauth1) to [nhjk/oauth](https://github.com/nhjk/oauth).

This uses the native Go `http` package and so we can set headers like normal, and as outlined by @AlexEfimov.

Working code as below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/nhjk/oauth"
)

func main() {

    ck := "consumer key"
    cs := "consumer secret"
    tk := "token key"
    ts := "token secret"

    // create an http client and a request for it to send
    client := new(http.Client)
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://www.example.com/api/rest/customers?limit=2&order=created_at&dir=DESC", nil)

    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")

    // a consumer allows you to authorize requests with a token
    cons := oauth.Consumer{ck, cs}

    // authorize request
    cons.Authorize(req, &oauth.Token{tk, ts})

    // send request and print body
    res, _ := client.Do(req)
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", body)
}
```